# Change the custom post type permalink

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have projects category in my theme ( custom post type ).

my link goes like this

> http://shaowtriger.com/project/naim/

my required link is

> http://shaowtriger.com/brands/naim/

I also have a page as

> http://shaowtriger.com/brands

I am confused how to get this.

Any suggestions on rewrite rules

Comment: Do not ask for plugin recommendations. That is off topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use rewrite arg in register_post_type. You can have custom post type name different then rewrite slug. For example here is the sample code with custom post type project and it shows pages with `http://shaowtriger.com/brands/naim/`

Notice rewrite in `$args`

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_brand_init' );
function codex_brand_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Brands', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Brand', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Brands', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Brand', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'brand', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Brand', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Brand', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Brand', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Brand', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Brands', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Brands', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Brands:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No brands found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No brands found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'brands' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'project', $args );
  flush_rewrite_rules();

}
```

Although having **only** base page `http://shaowtriger.com/brands/` should not interfere with CPT slug and functionality but having subpages to page brands will not work because then WordPress will look for CPT item instead of subpage.

Comment: i have this already in my functions.php with Projects in place of Brands ..i have changed that slug but its not working

Comment: You will also need to `flush_rewrite_rules();` and then visit permalink setting page again.

Comment: didnt get you ..where shud i use flush_rewrite_rules();

Comment: You can use it when you register CPT. I updated my code above and added `flush_rewrite_rules();`. You can ad this in your function similarly.

Comment: Never keep `flush_rewrite_rules();` It is a really expensive function to use. Use it **once** and delete it, otherwise hook it to an action that is run once, like when a theme of a plugin is activated

Comment: If you are familiar with the command-line interface, you can install wp-cli and use the command [wp rewrite flush](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/rewrite/flush/)

Comment: What if I would like to change the permalink further to `http://shaowtriger.com/brands/2018/naim/`
Meaning: `/brands/%year%/%postname%` ?
I found this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216337/change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type/216470#216470
But somehow dies does never have an effect. Does someone know an example with a bit more code, for example including the post registering like above? This would maybe help me a bit...