# Change permalink structure for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have 2 custom post types: `software` and `hardware`. For SEO reasons I would like to have the permalinks of single `software` and `hardware` pages like:

```
https://domain.com/custom-post-name/
```

But as default WordPress adds post-type slug on it like:

```
https://domain.com/post-type-slug/custom-post-name/
```

I've removed the slug with [following script](http://www.markwarddesign.com/2014/02/remove-custom-post-type-slug-permalink/) that makes a replacement of the string. Now the single page is reachable with both urls described above and Google search console find 2 pages with the exact same content which is not good for SEO.
Is it possible to change the complete structure of a permalink and get rid of custom post type slug?

```
register_post_type( 'hardware',
    array (
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'hardware-post_tag', 'hardware-category' ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'hardware' ),
    )
);
```

---

Comment: Please edit your question and let we know how did you use the `register_post_type`

Comment: ` //register post type
 register_post_type( 'hardware', array (
  'labels' => $labels,
  'has_archive' => true,
   'public' => true,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
  'taxonomies' => array( 'hardware-post_tag', 'hardware-category' ), 
  'exclude_from_search' => false,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'hardware' ),
        
        
  )
 ); `

Answer (score 7):

Note one Important thing to the above answer:

While it'll work fine from the first sight it will cause performance problems.
All this code will be called on `init` hook so every page load will cause it to run and `flush_rules()` is very time expensive.

So it's recomended to call flush rules upon theme\plugin activation only. Also you can use `add_permastruct` functions without need to access `global $wp_rewrite`

Final improved solution would be:

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite'); 
function my_custom_rewrite() {

    add_permastruct('hardware', '/%customname%/', false);
    add_permastruct('produkt', '/%customname%/', false);
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_custom_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_permalinks( $permalink, $post ) {
      return str_replace( '%customname%/', $post->post_name, $permalink );
}

 /* in case for plugin */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'my_custom_plugin_activate');
function my_custom_plugin_activate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}


/* in case of custom Theme in Functions.php */
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup');
function mytheme_setup () {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it using [`{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/field_no_prefix_save_pre/) with `post_name`.

```
/**
 * Customize permalinks.
 *
 * @param string $post_name
 *
 * @return string
 *   Returns a name-SKU combo for products, if all components are available.
 */
function my_custom_permalinks( $post_name ) {

    if (
        ($_POST['post_type'] !== 'product')
    ||  ($_POST['post_status'] === 'auto-draft')
    ) {
        return $post_name;
    }

    $post_name = sanitize_title_with_dashes(
        { modify $_POST['post_title'] as you please }
    );

    return $post_name;
}
add_filter('name_save_pre', 'my_custom_permalinks', 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

with usage of `$wp_rewrite` you can add a new permalink structure

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite');
function my_custom_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('hardware', '/%customname%/', false);
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('produkt', '/%customname%/', false);
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

then you replace your custom tag with `str_replace` when you filter the link url

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_custom_permalinks', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_permalinks( $permalink, $post ) {
    return str_replace( '%customname%/', $post->post_name, $permalink );
}
```

**NOTE: if you use this function the way is written (removing the post type slug from permalink) you can expect bad issues cause there is no control if you make a custom post permalink the same as a page or standard post**

Comment: It's a bad practice to flush rules on every page load (init action). You need to do it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming across this question who has encountered the dreaded link rot with the "following script" link mentioned in the question, here's the script [courtesy of the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805071318/https://www.markwarddesign.com/2014/02/12/remove-custom-post-type-slug-permalink/), with a correction to what I believe was an error in the code:

```
/**
 * Remove the slug from published post permalinks. Only affect our CPT though.
 */
function vipx_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'your_post_type' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $post_link;
    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vipx_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

function vipx_parse_request_tricksy( $query ) {
    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
        || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;
    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your_post_type', 'page' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vipx_parse_request_tricksy' );
```

Along with Mikhail's revision of 3ky's own solution, if like me it wasn't immediately obvious to you, I found it necessary to implement the `vipx_parse_request_tricksy()` function and corresponding action. But the `vipx_remove_cpt_slug()` function duplicates what `my_custom_permalinks()` does, so both aren't necessary—pick one?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `rewrite` argument for `register_post_type`, there is a `with_front` option to disable the default base that is prepended to the custom post type permalink. If you set this to false, `/blog/products/` for example becomes `/products/`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite

```php
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'products',
    'with_front' => false
)
```